# More efficient way to go through an array in PHP

Tags: php

I've created this method to change every value in an array. I'm kinda new to PHP, so I think there should be a more efficient way to do this.

Here's my code:

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $value)
{
     $my_array[$key] = htmlentities($value);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a more computationally efficient (faster) way, or a more efficient characters of code way (less typing)?  I doubt there is one for the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference the array and change it

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You'd probably be better off with array_map

```
$my_array = array_map( 'htmlentities' , $my_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you need to apply a function to the value and reassign it to the value, [Galen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875449/more-efficient-way-to-go-through-an-array-in-php/1875490#1875490) is a good solution. You could also use [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), although it doesn't read as easily as a nice, simple loop.

When you only need to assign, for example, a primitive value to each element in the array, the following will work.

- If your keys are numeric, you can use [array_fill()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

  ```
    array_fill(0, sizeof($my_array), "test");
  ```
- If you're using an associative array, you can probably use [array_fill_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), with something like:

  ```
    array_fill_keys(array_keys($my_array), "test");
  ```

Comment: This answer was written before the edit - the question previously had the loop assigning the value "test" to each array element. It's been updated with an assignment of htmlentities($value), which is more complex than just a simple string assignment.

Comment: I had the same 'problem' with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you mark $value as a [reference](http://docs.php.net/references) (&$value) any change you make on $value will effect the corresponding element in $my_array.

```
foreach($my_array as $key => &$value)
{
   $value = "test";
}
```

e.g.

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($my_array as &$value)
{
  $value *= 5;
}
echo join($my_array, ', ');
```

prints

```
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
```

(And there's also [array_map()](http://docs.php.net/array_map) if you want to keep the original array.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_fill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), starting at 0 and going to length `count($my_array)`. Not sure if it's better though.

**Edit:** Rob Hruska's `array_fill_keys` code is probably better depending on what you define as better (speed, standards, readability etc).

**Edit2**: Since you've now edited your question, these options are now no longer appropriate as you require the original value to be modified, not changed entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($my_array as &$value)
{
    $value = "test";
}
```